# failed to scrape friends on facebook using aiohttp but when using requests it works

Tags: python, async-await, aiohttp

I'm trying to get friends list but here it doesn't even work when I check using print(Dump) but it only shows empty and here I use aiohttp but when I use requests it works

here is the code for aiohttp

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import re

async def publik(userid, cookie, unit_cursor):
    headers = {
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/ apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'host': 'm.facebook.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/35.0.0.48.273;]',
        'accept-language': 'id,en;q=0.9',
    }
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, cookies={'cookie': cookie}) as session:
        async with session.get(f'https://m.facebook.com/profile.php?id={userid}&v=friends&unit_cursor={unit_cursor}') as response:
            text = await response.text()
            all_friends = re.findall('href="fb://profile/(.*?)">(.*?)<', text)
            for id_friends, name in all_friends:
                name = name.lower()
                if not (0 < len(name) <= 100) or str(id_friends) in str(Dump):
                    continue
                print(f'[$] dump user {id_friends}/{len(Dump)}', end='\r')
                await asyncio.sleep(0.0007)
                Dump.append(f'{id_friends}|{name}')
            if 'Sorry, something went wrong.' in text:
                await asyncio.sleep(2.1)
                return 0
            elif 'unit_cursor=' in text:
                try:
                    unit_cursor = re.search('unit_cursor=(.*?)&', text).group(1)
                    return await publik(userid, cookie, unit_cursor)
                except AttributeError:
                    await asyncio.sleep(2.1)
                    return 2
            else:
                return 0

# Inisialisasi list Dump sebelum menjalankan fungsi publik
Dump = []

userid = '100020958408145'
cookie = 'sb=K8DhZFiK6wPGlgzcw8LVu6F6; wd=980x1840; datr=K8DhZNDfRXcfahLHO1ru8Lu9; c_user=61550081050717; xs=49%3AW1FdPhrVqxwO7Q%3A2%3A1692517861%3A-1%3A-1; presence=C%7B%22t3%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22utc3%22%3A1692517909130%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D; dpr=2.75; fr=0oz0sLXg63zA3RRJJ.AWUGBbqzDbkk5njUvRxqDnEOVFo.Bk4cAr.Be.AAA.0.0.Bk4cXz.AWU_vlrVyHM'

# Menjalankan fungsi publik dengan parameter yang sesuai
asyncio.run(publik(userid, cookie, unit_cursor=''))
print(Dump)
```

and here is the code for requests

```
def publik(userid, cookie, unit_cursor):
    with requests.Session() as sr:
        headers = {
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/ apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'host': 'm.facebook.com',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/35.0.0.48.273;]',
            'accept-language': 'id,en;q=0.9',
        }
        sr.headers.update(headers)
        sr.cookies.update({'cookie': cookie})
        response = sr.get(f'https://m.facebook.com/profile.php?id={userid}&v=friends&unit_cursor={unit_cursor}').text
        all_friends = re.findall('href="fb://profile/(.*?)">(.*?)<', response)
        for id_friends, name in all_friends:
            name = name.lower()
            if not (0 < len(name) <= 100) or str(id_friends) in str(Dump):
                continue
            print(f'[$] dump user {id_friends}/{len(Dump)}', end='\r')
            time.sleep(0.0007)
            Dump.append(f'{id_friends}|{name}')
        if 'Sorry, something went wrong.' in response:
            time.sleep(2.1)
            return 0
        elif 'unit_cursor=' in response:
            try:
                unit_cursor = re.search('unit_cursor=(.*?)&', response).group(1)
                publik(userid, cookie, unit_cursor)
            except AttributeError:
                time.sleep(2.1)
                return 2
        else:
            return 0
```

what i want is so that the aiohttp code can get my friend list because when the scrap appears it's only empty but when using requests it runs smoothly please help me because i'm already having a hard time finding what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

AioHttp is more strict in passing cookies than requests.  It's doing the equivalent of blocking third party cookies https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#cookie-safety

> **Cookie Safety¶**
>
> By default ClientSession uses strict version of aiohttp.CookieJar. RFC
> 2109 explicitly forbids cookie accepting from URLs with IP address
> instead of DNS name (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:80/cookie).
>
> It’s good but sometimes for testing we need to enable support for such
> cookies. It should be done by passing unsafe=True to aiohttp.CookieJar
> constructor:

You have two options, you can set the `cookie` header yourself, and aiohttp will send it to facebook.  e.g.::

```
async def publik(userid, cookie, unit_cursor):
    headers = {
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/ apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'host': 'm.facebook.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/35.0.0.48.273;]',
        'accept-language': 'id,en;q=0.9',
        'cookie': cookie,
    }
```

Or you can follow the AioHttp example from the link above, and set your own custom cookie jar, with `unsafe=True`.